# Diffing algorithm: Obtaining timestamps of spoken syllables given actual transcript

Tags: algorithm, diff, speech-to-text, linear-interpolation, transcription

I have an audio file that is a recording of a person speaking different letters in sequence, along with a correct, human created transcript of this audio file, e.g. a string `ABCDEF`.

This audio file is then passed into a speech-to-text transcription API, and I'm given an ordered mapping of each character to the timestamp that it occurred (began) in the audio clip. For example, for a simple 5 second clip, the mapping may look like:

`['A' => 0.2, 'B' => 1.5, 'C' => 2.2, 'D' => 3.2, 'E' => 3.8, 'F' => 4.2]`

The twist is that this timestamp mapping returned from the API occasionally incorrectly transcribes the letters. In addition to just mistaking a letter for a different one (replacement), it could perceive that letters exist that in fact do not (insertions), or omit spoken letters entirely (removals). For example, the audio containing `ABCDEF` may have an API response like:

`['A' => 0.2, 'B' => 1.5, 'C' => 2.2, 'X' => 2.8, 'D' => 3.2, 'E' => 3.8, 'F' => 4.2]`

**The ultimate desired result here is to reconcile the actual transcript and the potentially erroneous letter-to-timestamp mapping from the API to obtain the timestamps of when each letter was actually spoken in the clip**. I believe I can use some linear interpolation along with a diffing algorithm to reach an ideal solution, but need some guidance on getting started. Thank you.

*Note: the "letters" in this example are in practice actually Mandarin Chinese characters, but for the sake of example I use letters as they are monosyllabic and easier to visualize.*